# Can't add a file separated with space to git

Tags: linux, git, bash, scripting, commit

I have been writing a script to add untracked files using git add .
The loop I use in my script is

```
for FILE in $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard); do  
git add $FILE  
git commit -m "Added $FILE"  
git push origin master  
done
```

The script runs fine till it faces a filename which has space in it. for Eg., I cant add the file `Hello 22.mp4`.(Note that there is a **SPACE** between Hello and 22). The above loop would take the file as 2 separate files, **Hello** and **22.mp4** and exit with error.
Does someone know how to add it as a single file?
Thanks

Comment: Don't use capitals for your bash variables, those are reserved for global environment vars. You don't want to accidentally collide with one of those

Comment: And as a general rule, don't use spaces in filenames. Better use underscores.

Comment: @SiegeX thanks for the tip. I was unaware of that. I'll definitely change it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's kind of a dumb rule.  The filesystem supports it.  Therefore you should be writing your scripts to handle  that (rightly valid) use case instead of pretending it doesn't exist.

Comment: Linux Ext3 filesystems also support control characters in filenames (all characters except null and slash). This is not a reason to use them. And few scripts are able to deal with all of them. A more reasonable rule is to avoid them (even if in theory it should work).

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but is there any particular reason "git add --all" wouldn't work for you instead of scripting it?

Comment: Well.. I thought about it and gave it a try, but for some reason(that i don't remember--it was a long time ago), it didn't work.. Maybe someone could point out what it was!!

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening is the shell is expanding the `$(...)` into a bunch of words, and it's obviously interpreting a file with spaces embedded as multiple files obviously.  **Even with the prior suggestions of quoting the `git add` command, it wouldn't work**. So the loop is getting run with wrong arguments, as shown by this output with `set -x`:

```
ubuntu@up:~/test$ ls -1
a a
ubuntu@up:~/test$ set -x; for FILE in $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard); do git add "$FILE"; git commit -m "Added $FILE"; done
+ set -x
++ git ls-files -o --exclude-standard
+ for FILE in '$(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)'
+ git add a
...
```

The proper solution is to quote the `git add $file` *and* have `git ls-files` NULL separate the filenames by passing `-z` to `git ls-files` and use a while loop with a null delimiter:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard -z | while read -r -d '' file; do
  git add "$file"
  git commit -m "Added $file"
  git push origin master
done
```

Comment: Hey.. That worked.. Thanks AndrewF.. It means a lot to me.. I'm a newbie here trying to study scripting.. Could you help me understand the working? Y should we use a pipe, -z and while? Don't we need a 'for' loop in first line?

Comment: For this case, you can't use a for loop.  What happens is that the subshell ($()) is taking this "a.txt", "b a.txt" and turning it into "a.txt b a.txt" and the for loop doesn't know that b and b.txt are the same.  You have to use a different delimiter other than space.  The null delimiter is used instead, not to mention that it's always the safer option than just assuming files don't contain spaces.  Because you can't use a for loop, you have to use `while read`.  You'll find that the "find" command and "xargs" both support NULL delimited input.  Don't forget to accept your chosen answer.

Comment: You also have to clear `IFS` with `read`, like this: `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ... done`. Otherwise, any leading and trailing whitespaces will be stripped.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bash alternative to the solution provided by @AndrewF, you can make use of [IFS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF) bash internal variable to change the delimiter from space to newline, something on these lines:

```
(IFS=$'\n'
for FILE in $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard); do  
git add $FILE  
git commit -m "Added $FILE"  
git push origin master  
done 
)
```

This is just for your information. The response of AndrewF is more informative covering debugging option & usage of while instead of for.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `$FILE` var in quotes:

```
git add "$FILE"
```

That'll quote the filename, thus allowing spaces in it.

Comment: Hmm.. It seemed to be a good idea... But even after trying as "$FILE", I receive the same error.. Means the git doesn't track the file..

Answer (score 1):

Replace `git add $FILE` with `git add "$FILE"`. That way it will be interpreted as a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very late but here is one way to do it using the standard xargs linux command:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | xargs -L 1 -I{} -d '\n' git add '{}'
```

You can test it by simply echoing the command as follows:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | xargs -L 1 -I{} -d '\n' echo "git add '{}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add as a single file add a backslash before the space in the filename:

git add pathtofilename/filenamewith\ space.txt